# duplicate results when sorting by collection property

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Repost from [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-744)

Given entities and repository:

```
@Entity
public final class Partner {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Merchant> merchants;

    ...
}

@Entity
public final class Merchant {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Partner partner;

    ...
}

public interface PartnerRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Partner, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Partner> {

}
```

If there is only one partner having two merchants in the DB then the following code incorrectly returns list with two instances of the same parnter.

```
partnerRepository.findAll(new Sort("merchants.name"));
```

This is caused internally by the DB join. By creating custom implementation that adds the distinct to the selection the result is correctly the single partner.

Wouldn't it be correct to do distinct selection per default?

Comment: may be you have missed sorting order `desc` or `asc` here:  `new Sort("merchants.name")`

Comment: @user404 yes, It still get duplicated records.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "partner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("name")
private List<Merchant> merchants;
```